# Is it possible to extract trained class names from tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

I have tried to search everywhere, tried everything in `tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='model.tflite')`, read tflite documentation but I cannot find the method to extract the class names from the model.

Is it possible?

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305406/how-to-visualize-detected-boxes-from-tflite-model-how-to-get-category-index-fro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create data for training, you encode the labels to numerical representations. After that the labels are lost, if you know the data with which the model was trained, then, you can know the label_names. Information of label_names is not stored in the model.

Comment: so this should be done let's say 'by hand' if i want for example represent real classes with their probabilities ?

Comment: If you have the labels and encoding them yourselves, then you have the mapping for them. If you don't have the training labels or the mapping from labels to numbers, then, it can only be left to the imagination. Most of the datasets provide the mapping file or provide the original labels so that you can convert them to numbers yourself.