# How to visualize detected boxes from TFLite model (How to get category index from TFLite model?)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have an object detection TFLite model saved as `model.tflite` file. I can run it as

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter("model.tflite")

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_image)

interpreter.invoke()
```

and then get the output as

```
detection_boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
detection_classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
detection_scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])
num_boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])
```

I would like to plot the detected boxes with given classes in a picture. The simplest solution to do this seems to be using the tool `viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` as.

```
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np_with_detections,
        detection_boxes,
        detection_classes,
        detection_scores,
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        max_boxes_to_draw=20,
        min_score_thresh=.1,
        agnostic_mode=False
```

However, for that one needs to have the `category_index` (to convert the classes indices to human readable labels). Typically, you can load it from a file containing the labels, which, in case of .tflite model, should be included/packed in the .tflite file, if I am not wrong.

However, I can't figure out how to do it, or which functions should I use (I looked also at `tflite_support` library, but can't figure out how to extract the categories from the associated file).

What is the proper way to visualize the detected boxes with labels using a .tflite file? It doesn't have to be using `viz_utils`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7458#issuecomment-523904465

Comment: @JaesungChung In that example they refer to tensorflow, not TFLite, but even though, my problem is that I don't have `path_to_labels` (from that example). I have only the packed tflite model file - I think that the labels should be extractable from that file. But, maybe that's where I am wrong.

Comment: for idx, box in enumerate(detection_boxes'][0]):
    if output_dict['detection_scores'][0][idx] > treshold:
        class_name = category_index[int(output_dict['detection_classes'][0][idx])]['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# labels variable contains the list of the names of the category and
# it generates by reading the labels.txt
with open("labels.txt", "r") as f:
  txt = f.read()

labels = txt.splitlines()

for idx, box in enumerate(detection_boxes[0]):
    if detection_scores[0][idx] > threshold:
        class_name = labels[int(detection_classes[0][idx])]
```

I created this code snippet based on the  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7458#issuecomment-523904465.

Comment: From where do you get `category_index` if you have only mode.tflite and dict.txt?

Comment: Are you saying that the labels which I get in detection_classes are indexed by the row number in labels.txt?

Comment: Yes, the detection_classes stores the Class indices detected.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I am asking. But it seems you are right anyway. The order in which the labels are stored in the dict.txt correspond to class ids which are returned from the model. Very interesting. I could not find it in any documentation.

Comment: FYI, https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/object_detection/mobile_object_localizer_v1/1/metadata/1

Comment: Not sure, what I should see there. But thanks for you help.